# ML.NET plotting K-means clustering results?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm experimenting with ML.NET in an unsupervised clustering scenario. My start data are less than 30 records with 5 features in a TSV file, e.g. (of course the label will be ignored):

```
Label   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5
alpha   0.274167987321712   0.483359746434231   0.0855784469096672   0.297939778129952   0.0332805071315372
beta   0.378208470054279   0.405409549510871   0.162317151706584   0.292342604802355   0.0551994848048085
...
```

My start point was the [iris tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/iris-clustering), a sample of K-means clustering. In my case I want 3 clusters. As I'm just learning, once created the model I'd like to use it to add the clustering data to each record in a copy of the original file, so I can examine them and plot scatter graphs.

I started with this training code (say `MyModel` is the POCO class representing its model, with properties for `S1`-`S5`):

```cs
// load data
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<MyModel>
    (dataPath, hasHeader: true, separatorChar: '\t');

// train model
const string featuresColumnName = "Features";
EstimatorChain<ClusteringPredictionTransformer<KMeansModelParameters>>
    pipeline = mlContext.Transforms
    .Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5")
    .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName,
    numberOfClusters: 3));

TransformerChain<ClusteringPredictionTransformer<KMeansModelParameters>>
    model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);

// save model
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(modelPath,
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    mlContext.Model.Save(model, dataView.Schema, fileStream);
}
```

Then, I load the saved model, read every record from the original data, and get its cluster ID. This sounds a bit convoluted, but my learning intent here is inspecting the results, before playing with them. The results should be saved in a new file, together with the centroids coordinates and the points coordinates.

Yet, it does not seem that this API is transparent enough to easily access the centroids; I found only a [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c09171c0-d9c8-4426-83a9-36ed72a32fe7/kmeans-output-centroids-and-cluster-size?forum=MachineLearning), which is rather old, and its code no more compiles. I rather used it as a hint to recover the data via reflection, but this is a hack.

Also, I'm not sure about the details of the data provided by the framework. I can see that every centroid has 3 vectors (named `cx` `cy` `cz` in the sample code), each with 5 elements (the 5 features, in their concatenated input order, I presume, i.e. from S1 to S5); also, each prediction provides a 3-fold distance (`dx` `dy` `dz`). If these assumptions are OK, I could assign a cluster ID to each record like this:

```cs
// for each record in the original data
foreach (MyModel record in csvReader.GetRecords<MyModel>())
{
    // get its cluster ID
    MyPrediction prediction = predictor.Predict(record);

    // get the centroids just once, as of course they are the same
    // for all the records referring their distances to them
    if (cx == null)
    {
        // get centroids (via reflection...):
        // https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/Trainers/Clustering/KMeansWithOptions.cs#L49
        // https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c09171c0-d9c8-4426-83a9-36ed72a32fe7/kmeans-output-centroids-and-cluster-size?forum=MachineLearning
        VBuffer<float>[] centroids = default;
        var last = ((TransformerChain<ITransformer>)model)
            .LastTransformer;
        KMeansModelParameters kparams = (KMeansModelParameters)
            last.GetType().GetProperty("Model").GetValue(last);
        kparams.GetClusterCentroids(ref centroids, out int k);
        cx = centroids[0].GetValues().ToArray();
        cy = centroids[1].GetValues().ToArray();
        cz = centroids[2].GetValues().ToArray();
    }

    float dx = prediction.Distances[0];
    float dy = prediction.Distances[1];
    float dz = prediction.Distances[2];
    // ... calculate and save full details for the record ...
}
```

Given this scenario, I suppose I can get all the details about each record position in a pretrained model in the following way:

- `dx`, `dy`, `dz` are the distances.
- `cx[0]` `cy[0]` `cy[0]` + the distances (`dx`, `dy`, and `dz` respectively) should be the position of the S1 point; `cx[1]` `cy[1]` `cz[1]` + the distances the position of S2; and so forth up to S5 (`cx[4]` etc).

In this case, I could plot these data in a 3D scatter graph. Yet, I'm totally new to ML.NET, and thus I'm not sure about these assumptions, and it's well possible I'm on the wrong path. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured this out myself - took a bit of digging so for those interested heres some good info:

The centroids can now be retrieved right off the fit model via

```
VBuffer<float>[] centroids = default;
var modelParams = trainedModel.Model;
modelParams.GetClusterCentroids(ref centroids, out var k);
```

However the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.kmeansclusteringextensions.kmeans?view=ml-dotnet) is annoyingly misleading because the centroids they claim are "coordinates" are not coordinates but rather the mean values of the features columns for the cluster.

Based on your pipeline this probably makes them pretty useless if like me you have 700 feature columns and half a dozen transformation steps.  As far as I can tell (**please correct me if I'm wrong anyone!!!**) there is no way to transform the centroids into Cartesian coordinates for charting.

But we can still use them.

What I ended up doing was after training my model on my data I ran all my data through the model's prediction function.  This gives me the predicted cluster id and euclidean distances to all other cluster centroids.

Using the predicted cluster id and the centroid means for the cluster you can map your datapoint's features over the means to get a "weighted value" of your data row based on the predicted cluster.  Basically a centroid will contain info that it contains a certain column 0.6533, and another column 0.211, and another column 0.  By running your datapoint features, lets say ( 5, 3, 1 ), through the centroid you'll get ( 3.2665, 0.633, 0 ).  Which is a representation of the data row as included in the predicted cluster.

This is still just a row of data however - to make them into Cartesian coordinates for a point graph I simply use a sum of the first half as X and a sum of the second half as Y.  For the example data the coord would be ( 3.8995, 0 )

Doing this we can finally get pretty charts[image]

And here's a mostly complete code example:

```
VBuffer<float>[] centroids = default;
var modelParams = trainedModel.Model;
modelParams.GetClusterCentroids(ref centroids, out var k);

// extract from the VBuffer for ease
var cleanCentroids = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToDictionary(x => (uint)x, x =>
{
    var values = centroids[x - 1].GetValues().ToArray();
    return values;
});



var points = new Dictionary<uint, List<(double X, double Y)>>();
foreach (var dp in featuresDataset)
{
    var prediction = predictor.Predict(dp);

    var weightedCentroid = cleanCentroids[prediction.PredictedClusterId].Zip(dp.Features, (x, y) => x * y);
    var point = (X: weightedCentroid.Take(weightedCentroid.Count() / 2).Sum(), Y: weightedCentroid.Skip(weightedCentroid.Count() / 2).Sum());

     if (!points.ContainsKey(prediction.PredictedClusterId))
         points[prediction.PredictedClusterId] = new List<(double X, double Y)>();
     points[prediction.PredictedClusterId].Add(point);


}
```

Where `featuresDataset` is an array of objects that contain the feature columns being fed to the kmeans trainer.  See the microsoft docs link above for an example - `featuresDataset` would be `testData` in their sample.

Comment: Thanks this is very useful, even if meantime I moved to Python and Tensor Flow, so did not test this. Yet ML.NET is great for consuming models in your. Net stack.